# PHP using todays date to get the specific days of subsequent months

Tags: php, date

Have a booking system for a travel company. It gives the planner a few options on start dates, all of which should be the first saturday of each month. So the PHP would need to get todays date.

Then the following PHP in option box number 1 should use todays date to display the first saturday of next month. The second box show the month after that. etc.. etc..

Any help on how to do that would be marvellous.

Thanks

Comment: `date('Y-m-d',strtotime('first saturday of february 2011'));`

Comment: that appeared to do nothing on echo

Comment: Strange, cause it echoes as `'2011-02-05'` here. Anyway, explore `strtotime()` and formats it accepts.

Comment: Has been sufficiently answered before. Please use the Search Function ask was asked from you in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice before you submitted your question.

Comment: The word of is causing an error

Answer (score 0):

This example is quite verbose, but it should show the power of PHP 5.3's `DateTime` class and its relations.

```
<?php

$first_of_next_month = new DateTime('next month first day'); // get a start date

$a_day = new DateInterval('P1D');
$a_month = new DateInterval('P1M');

$start_dates = array();

foreach (new DatePeriod($first_of_next_month, $a_month, 11) as $day_of_month) {
    // $day_of_month is now the first day of the next month

    while ($day_of_month->format('w') != 6) {
    // while $day_of_month isn't a Saturday
        $day_of_month->add($a_day);
        // add a day
    }

    $start_dates[] =  $day_of_month;
}

foreach ($start_dates as $d) {
    echo $d->format('r'), "\n"; // or format how you like
}
```

Comment: Turned out in failure. Must not be on 5.3

Comment: Would there be no way of doing something like this code below. Obviously it does not work but all the solutions here are coming up in error <?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 month first saturday'));?>

Answer (score 0):

```
function next_ten_first_sat(){
    $next_month = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
    $j=0;
    for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
        if($i==1){
            $sat_next_month[$i] = strtotime('next month first saturday', $next_month);
            $next_month = strtotime(date('Y-m',$sat_next_month[$i]).'-01');
        }else{
            $sat_next_month[$i] = strtotime('next month first saturday', $next_month);
            $next_month = strtotime(date('Y-m',$sat_next_month[$i]).'-01');
            $result_year = date('Y', $sat_next_month[$i]);
            if(date('m', $sat_next_month[$i])>10){
                $result_month = date('m', $sat_next_month[$i])-1;
            }else{
                $result_month = date('m', $sat_next_month[$i])-1;
                $result_month = '0'.$result_month;
            }
            $result_date = date('d', $sat_next_month[$i]);
            $result_array[$j] = $result_year.'-'.$result_month.'-'.$result_date;
        }      
       $j++;
    }
    return $result_array;
}
```

Sorry guys first time misread the question. This should work as intended but its very messy... Please optimize it guys.....